# How do I change the keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard

I would like to know how to change my keyboard from an English layout to a Portuguese (Brazil) layout.

Answer (score 5):

To change the layout, go to `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Layout` tab.

Then, click the `+` sign at the bottom left part of the window, choose `Portuguese` in the language section and choose whatever Portuguese keyboard layout that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks friend!!!! See it, i would need this botton - ç, é, ó, à and "et coetera". Thank you again, friend!!!!

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have some visual cues, I made a video recently on how to do this, it's in Dutch, but if you follow the video, it's pretty clear on how to do it. [YouTube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c8vHVE_mtA)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout you want isn't included in the list, you can create one and add it following the instructions in this other answer [How to provide and select a custom keyboard layout (xkb methods failing)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-to-provide-and-select-a-custom-keyboard-layout-xkb-methods-failing)