# How can I switch between keyboard layouts with a keyboard shortcut in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

After having set-up multiple [keyboard layouts](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/735/how-do-i-change-the-keyboard-layout) how can I switch between them using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default shortcut for switching layouts is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you’d like to use a different shortcut, you can set one in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Universal Access as “Next Keyboard Layout”.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

However, it is not possible to select shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

You can do this through the terminal, but I strongly **not recommend** doing so, because you may have problems with other system shortcuts. If you still dare:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Shift>Alt_R']"`

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Ctrl>Shift_L', '<Ctrl>Shift_R', '<Shift>Control_L', '<Shift>Control_R']"`

Comment: Is alt-Space the default for that? I had the impression these keys showed window menu by default

Comment: perfect answer. I've been using shift+alt for years and I've never had any issues with that

Comment: @cuddlecheek this shortcut set as default on Loki ;)

Comment: @MaximTaranov Glad to hear that!

Comment: @MaximTaranov, is this screenshot from Freya? I don't have those two keyboard input lines in Loki

Comment: @Wolf yes it is Freya. Now Loki have reworked keyboard pane with settings of keyboard layouts in Layout tab.

Answer (score 0):

`Alt + Space`switches between your selected keyboard layouts

Answer (score 0):

see youtube (in dutch) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c8vHVE_mtA
go to system
then keyboard
then division
left corner under you see a +-sign, click it
then you will have a new window in witch you can choose a keyboard
after having choosed click "add division"
in the left column will appear the new keyboard

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Loki it's `Alt + Shift`