# Switch between keyboard layouts with a keyboard shortcut in Loki

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

[Another question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1128/5565) addresses a shortcut in Freya (0.3), but Alt+space is not working as a keyboard shortcut for me in Loki (0.4). Also it no longer shows as a custom shortcut in alongside the others:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

What are my options for switching between keyboard layouts in Loki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It defaults to <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in Loki.

To change it, go to: `Settings > Keyboard pane > Layout subtab > "Switch layout"`

[image: Keyboard Layout]

Commands like `gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>space']"` no longer appear to work in Loki.