# Can't switch between keyboard layouts via shortcuts - none of them work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Whatever shortcut I choose in system settings to switch between keyboard languages, it won't work. Tried all available combination - Alt+Shift, Ctrl+Alt, Alt+Space, etc.

What could cause this? I've already reinstalled elementaryOS - didn't help. I suspect something is wrong with my user configuration, but I don't know what. I don't want to reset all settings.

```
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.1.5
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hera
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera"
```

What can cause this issue? Is there a way to debug this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Keyboard settings]

For me it is working.

Next time, don't reinstall anything, just delete the ~/.Xauthority file, it will be recreated automatically next time you log in:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Then log in normally. Let me know did it solve the issue.

Other solutions are here: [How can I switch between keyboard layouts with a keyboard shortcut in Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/how-can-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-freya)

Comment: Deleted that file - still having he same issue

Comment: Try in terminal: sudo gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Shift>Alt_R']"

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help either

Comment: I edited my post and added another older thread. Check it. Maybe you will find the solution there.