# Add custom keymap, system preferences

Tags: keyboard

I have a custom keymap,  http://tlundqvist.org/sv_dvorak/drivers/se_sv_dvorak_new.xorg that I want to be able to select via system preferences.

I have copied the keymap to the other keymap files, naming it se_sv_dvorak.
I can load it with setxkbmap se_sv_dvorak, but how do I add it so it can be set via system preferences?

Answer (score 1):

My googlefu upped one level just after asking this question.
Seems like the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml shall be edited. At least in Ubuntu. Will try this later and report back.

Edit: Seems like this is not possible at the moment https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486857

Comment: This will not work right now, please see this question http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-to-provide-and-select-a-custom-keyboard-layout-xkb-methods-failing, there is also a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486857