# How To Select Dvorak Layout

Tags: release-hera, keyboard

I don't see any options for selecting Dvorak layout in US English (or any other languages).  How do I change to dvorak keyboard layout?

Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1 Hera
Release:    5.1
Codename:   hera

Comment: I have tried this option, but Dvorak is not listed
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/735/how-do-i-change-the-keyboard-layout?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under System-Settings -> Language & Region -> Keyboard Settings -> Input Method -> (Plus Sign)

Then you can use whichever shortcut you prefer to switch between layouts/engines. Default is Ctrl+Space.

Hit it twice and you'll see the two keyboard layouts. It will auto-hide if selected as option.

You will also need the Layout changed. Under Keyboard Settings, use the Plus sign (bottom left) to add the English US, it will then bring you to a sub-list of the English US keyboards. There's multiple options for dvorak, left, right, balanced, etc.

Hope this helps!